# formatting the output of a UNIX file

Tags: grep, cat

I have a file that contains the following information:

```
uid: jdoe
mail: jdoe@yahoo.com
```

How do I make the output to look like the following

```
uid: jdoe mail: jdoe@yahoo.com
```

I appreciate any information.

Comment: The file looks like this when you cat it

Comment: uid: jdoe
mail: jdoe@yahoo.com

Comment: I am sorry, looks like

Comment: So what you want it to be look like ?

Comment: I added formatting to your post; see if that's how you want it to look.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo `cat file.txt`
```

or

```
tr "\n" " " < file.txt
```

If replacing newline with space is really all you want. If there are other lines you want to ignore then:

```
echo $(egrep "^(uid|mail):" file.txt)
```

Comment: `xargs -a filename` will also do the trick.

Comment: `echo $(< file.txt)`, to use `echo` without `cat`

Answer (score 0):

`cat ${FILENAME} | tr '\n' ' '`

where `${FILENAME}` is the file containing your data.  [`tr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) will replace every instance of newline (first element of first argument) with a space (first element of second argument).

Comment: `tr '\n' ' ' <filename` will do the trick. No need to use `cat`

Comment: I have a big files, all entries start with uid or mail 
uid: jdoe mail: jdoe@yahoo.com  or  mail: jdoe@yahoo.com uid: 
how can I make all lines start with uid